# How to create server-side pagination to get data in SharePoint list through SPFx-react?

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, spfx, react, paging

How to create server-side pagination to get data in SharePoint list through SPFx-react?

Current code I am using:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
// import { sp } from "@pnp/sp/presets/all";
// import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";
// import { sp } from 'sp-rest-explorer';
import {
  SPHttpClient,
  SPHttpClientResponse,
} from "@microsoft/sp-http";
import { Spinner } from "react-bootstrap";
import { IAllPublishDocumentProps } from "./IAllPublishDocumentProps";

export const PublishDoc = (props: IAllPublishDocumentProps) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [PublishDocument, setPublishDocuments] = useState([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const pageSize = 10;

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [currentPage]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const url = `${props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestPerformance')/items?&$top=10`;

      const response: SPHttpClientResponse =
        await props.context.spHttpClient.get(
          url,
          SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
          {
            headers: {
              Accept: "application/json;odata=nometadata",
              "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
              "odata-version": "",
            },
          }
        );
      const responsejson = await response.json();
      console.log(responsejson);

      const newData = responsejson.value.map((item: any) => ({
        ID: item.ID,
        GuidData: item.RUID,
        OrignalID: item.OrignalID,
        OLDTagID: item.OldTagId,
        DocumentID: item.DocID,
        DocumentName: item.DocumentName,
        DocumentType: item.DocumentType,
        SubmissionDate: item.Created,
        RequestedBy: item.AuthorName,
        Version: item.RevisionNo,
        PublishDocument: item.DocName,
        PublishDocument2:
          props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl +
          "/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=" +
          encodeURIComponent(item.EncodedAbsUrl),
      }));
      let url2 = `${props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestPerformance')/items?$top=${pageSize}&$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&p_ID=${newData[9].ID}`;

      let nextdata = await props.context.spHttpClient.get(
        url2,
        SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
        {
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=nometadata",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
            "odata-version": "",
          },
        }
      );
      const nextdatajson = await nextdata.json();
      console.log(nextdatajson);

      setPublishDocuments(newData);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const handlePageClick = (pageNumber: number) => {
    setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {isLoading ? (
        <div
          className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center"
          style={{ height: "100vh" }}
        >
          <Spinner animation="border" role="status" className="mb-2">
            <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span>
          </Spinner>
          <p>Document loading...</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">
              <div className="card">
                <div
                  className="card-heading text-center"
                  style={{ backgroundColor: "#ffe525", paddingTop: "5px" }}
                >
                  <h3 className="text-black">All Published Document</h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="card-body" style={{ padding: "0px" }}>
                <div className="row">
                  <div
                    className="col-md-12 col-sm-11 col-xs-9"
                    style={{ fontSize: "small" }}
                  >
                    <nav
                      className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light"
                      style={{
                        backgroundColor: "#edeccc87",
                        fontWeight: "bold",
                      }}
                    >
                      <div
                        className="col-md-6 col-sm-1 col-xs-12"
                        style={{ paddingRight: "0px" }}
                      >
                        <button
                          style={{
                            padding: "0px",
                            marginLeft: "5px;",
                            borderRadius: "3px",
                          }}
                          className="navbar-toggler"
                          type="button"
                          // data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                          // data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                          // aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                          // aria-expanded="false"
                          // aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                        >
                          <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>

                        <div
                          style={{ width: "" }}
                          className="collapse navbar-collapse"
                          id="navbarSupportedContent"
                        >
                          <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                            {" "}
                            <li className="nav-item active">
                              {" "}
                              <a
                                className="nav-link"
                                // href="https://credentinfotec.sharepoint.com/sites/testPortal/SitePages/DMSDashboard.aspx"
                                href={
                                  props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl +
                                  "/SitePages/NEWDMSDASHBOARD.aspx"
                                }
                              >
                                Home
                              </a>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item" id="TempNav">
                              <a
                                className="nav-link"
                                // href="https://credentinfotec.sharepoint.com/sites/testPortal/SitePages/DMSTemplate.aspx"
                                href={
                                  props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl +
                                  "/SitePages/DMSTemplate.aspx"
                                }
                              >
                                Templates
                              </a>
                            </li>{" "}
                            <li className="nav-item">
                              <a className="nav-link" href="#">
                                Reports
                              </a>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item" id="adminPanel">
                              <a
                                className="nav-link"
                                href={
                                  props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl +
                                  "/SitePages/MasterListUpdate.aspx"
                                }
                              >
                                Admin Panel
                              </a>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item" id="archiveDoc">
                              <a
                                className="nav-link"
                                // href="https://credentinfotec.sharepoint.com/sites/testPortal/SitePages/ArchivalDocument.aspx"
                                href={
                                  props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl +
                                  "/SitePages/ArchivalDocument.aspx"
                                }
                              >
                                Archive
                              </a>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item" id="expireDocument">
                              <a
                                className="nav-link"
                                href={
                                  props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl +
                                  "/SitePages/ExpiredDocument.aspx"
                                }
                              >
                                Expired Document
                              </a>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item" id="approvalRoute">
                              <a
                                className="nav-link"
                                // // href="https://credentinfotec.sharepoint.com/sites/testPortal/SitePages/approvalRoutePage.aspx"
                                href={
                                  props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl +
                                  "/SitePages/approvalRoutePage.aspx"
                                }
                              >
                                Approval route Creation
                              </a>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="col-md-6">
                        <a
                          href={
                            props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl +
                            "/SitePages/NEWDMSDASHBOARD.aspx"
                          }
                        >
                          <button
                            style={{ marginLeft: "5px", float: "right" }}
                            type="button"
                            // value="Exit"
                            className="btn btn-danger"
                          >
                            Exit
                          </button>
                        </a>
                        <a
                          href={
                            props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl +
                            "/SitePages/PublishPermissionPage.aspx"
                          }
                        >
                          <button
                            type="button"
                            id="givePermissionBtn"
                            style={{ float: "right", display: "none" }}
                            className="btn btn-primary"
                            // onClick={ModalBoxopen}
                          >
                            Give Permission
                          </button>
                        </a>
                      </div>

                      {/* Coding For Modal Box */}
                    </nav>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-12">
              <div
                className="table-responsive"
                style={{ overflowX: "auto", marginTop: "10px" }}
              >
                <table
                  className="table"
                  style={{ width: "100%", borderCollapse: "collapse" }}
                >
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th
                        style={{
                          padding: "10px",
                          borderBottom: "1px solid #ddd",
                          background: "#f2f2f2",
                        }}
                      >
                        <span style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}>OLDTagID</span>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          placeholder="Enter your TagID"
                          style={{
                            padding: "5px",
                            borderRadius: "5px",
                            border: "1px solid #ccc",
                          }}
                        />
                      </th>
                      <th
                        style={{
                          padding: "10px",
                          borderBottom: "1px solid #ddd",
                          background: "#f2f2f2",
                        }}
                      >
                        <span style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}>DocumentID</span>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          placeholder="Enter your DocumentID"
                          style={{
                            padding: "5px",
                            borderRadius: "5px",
                            border: "1px solid #ccc",
                          }}
                        />
                      </th>
                      <th
                        style={{
                          padding: "10px",
                          borderBottom: "1px solid #ddd",
                          background: "#f2f2f2",
                        }}
                      >
                        <span style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}>DocumentName</span>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          placeholder="Enter your DocumentName"
                          style={{
                            padding: "5px",
                            borderRadius: "5px",
                            border: "1px solid #ccc",
                          }}
                        />
                      </th>
                      <th
                        style={{
                          padding: "10px",
                          borderBottom: "1px solid #ddd",
                          background: "#f2f2f2",
                        }}
                      >
                        <span style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}>DocumentType</span>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          placeholder="Enter your DocumentType"
                          style={{
                            padding: "5px",
                            borderRadius: "5px",
                            border: "1px solid #ccc",
                          }}
                        />
                      </th>
                      <th
                        style={{
                          padding: "10px",
                          borderBottom: "1px solid #ddd",
                          background: "#f2f2f2",
                        }}
                      >
                        <span style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}>
                          SubmissionDate
                        </span>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          placeholder="Enter your SubmissionDate"
                          style={{
                            padding: "5px",
                            borderRadius: "5px",
                            border: "1px solid #ccc",
                          }}
                        />
                      </th>
                      <th
                        style={{
                          padding: "10px",
                          borderBottom: "1px solid #ddd",
                          background: "#f2f2f2",
                        }}
                      >
                        <span style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}>RequestedBy</span>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          placeholder="Enter your RequestedBy"
                          style={{
                            padding: "5px",
                            borderRadius: "5px",
                            border: "1px solid #ccc",
                          }}
                        />
                      </th>
                      <th
                        style={{
                          padding: "10px",
                          borderBottom: "1px solid #ddd",
                          background: "#f2f2f2",
                        }}
                      >
                        <span style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}>Version</span>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          placeholder="Enter your Version"
                          style={{
                            padding: "5px",
                            borderRadius: "5px",
                            border: "1px solid #ccc",
                          }}
                        />
                      </th>
                      <th
                        style={{
                          padding: "10px",
                          borderBottom: "1px solid #ddd",
                          background: "#f2f2f2",
                        }}
                      >
                        <span style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}>
                          PublishedDocument
                        </span>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          placeholder="Enter your PublishedDocument"
                          style={{
                            padding: "5px",
                            borderRadius: "5px",
                            border: "1px solid #ccc",
                          }}
                        />
                      </th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    {PublishDocument.map((data: any, index: number) => (
                      <tr
                        key={index}
                        style={{ borderBottom: "1px solid #ddd" }}
                      >
                        {/* <td style={{ padding: "10px" }}>{data.OLDTagID}</td> */}
                        <td
                          style={{ border: "1px solid #ddd", padding: "5px" }}
                        >
                          {data.OLDTagID}
                        </td>
                        <td
                          style={{ border: "1px solid #ddd", padding: "5px" }}
                        >
                          {data.DocumentID}
                        </td>
                        <td
                          style={{ border: "1px solid #ddd", padding: "8px" }}
                        >
                          {data.DocumentName}
                        </td>
                        <td
                          style={{ border: "1px solid #ddd", padding: "8px" }}
                        >
                          {data.DocumentType}
                        </td>
                        <td
                          style={{ border: "1px solid #ddd", padding: "8px" }}
                        >
                          {data.SubmissionDate}
                        </td>
                        <td
                          style={{ border: "1px solid #ddd", padding: "8px" }}
                        >
                          {data.RequestedBy}
                        </td>
                        <td
                          style={{ border: "1px solid #ddd", padding: "8px" }}
                        >
                          {data.Version}
                        </td>
                        <td
                          style={{ border: "1px solid #ddd", padding: "8px" }}
                        >
                          {data.PublishDocument}
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    ))}
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>

              <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
                <ul className="pagination">
                  <li
                    className={`page-item ${
                      currentPage === 1 ? "disabled" : ""
                    }`}
                  >
                    <button
                      className="page-link"
                      onClick={() => handlePageClick(currentPage - 1)}
                    >
                      Previous
                    </button>
                  </li>

                  {/* Assuming you have at least one page */}
                  <li className="page-item">
                    <button
                      className="page-link"
                      onClick={() => handlePageClick(1)}
                    >
                      1
                    </button>
                  </li>

                  <li
                    className={`page-item ${
                      PublishDocument.length < pageSize ? "disabled" : ""
                    }`}
                  >
                    <button
                      className="page-link"
                      onClick={() => handlePageClick(currentPage + 1)}
                    >
                      Next
                    </button>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>

          {/* // -----------------Re-loader------------------- */}
          {!isLoading && PublishDocument.length === 0 && (
            <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>No data available</div>
          )}
          {/* )} */}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I'm trying to make server-side pagination to get the data in SharePoint list through SPFx react but problem is on the next click not giving me next 10 entry/data of list its give me same data every time in both API in second API I am sending my last id and I want the next 10 data of my last id.